# How to prevent snakes from eating goldfish in pond?

Tags: snakes, goldfish, pond

Some snake found its way into my pond. I heard that local snakes will eat the fish. The pond is 1/2 underground and 1/2 above ground with a 2 ft high brick wall all the way around. Is there some strategy I can use to keep snakes out?

Comment: what are the size of your goldfish and what type of snakes do you have where you live and how large are the snakes.

Comment: http://www.pondexpert.co.uk/there-way-deter-grass-snakes-from-pond.html i have had garden ponds for 30+years and grass snakes live around my pond and i have never lost any fish to snakes,i wonder if protecting the pond against snakes is something you need to put time and money into the risk is very low but not zero for your fish.

Answer (score 3):

The snakes stop eating fish when there are no more fish. You can try killing the snakes, but they are fast. I did kill one by putting a fish trap under the water; the snake went in, could not find the opening and drowned. If the snake is slow and mostly black, it is probably a cottonmouth, which does not eat many fish, but you shouldn't mess with it.

Comment: I have killed several snakes over the years . Here the fish eaters are yellow bellied and green water snakes. Otherwise I leave snakes alone , the copper heads are very docile and eat mice,etc.